# How to handle (let := _ in _) in assumptions

Tags: coq

I am new to Coq and learning it.

I encountered a situation where `(let := _ in _) = _` appears as assumption, which cannot be True.

More specifically, it seems like:

```
H: (let (l1, l2) := f l in (a :: l1, l2)) = ([], [])
----------------------------------------------------
False
```

Intuitively, `a :: l1` cannot be `[]`, but I got no clue to getting over it.

How should I tackle this case? Thanks!

Comment: Note that that's not actually a `let`. A real let is `let ident := expr in expr`, not with a pattern. This one is just syntax sugar for a `match`: `H: match f l with (l1, l2) => (a :: l1, l2) end = ([], [])`. The accepted answer will work to reduce any `match` in the assumptions or the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`destruct (f l); discriminate.` should do the job. This will let reduction proceed in `H` and Coq will not have trouble seeing the contradiction.